# Similar words for 'most talked about' story

Tags: phrase-request

Consider this expression:

> One of **the most talked about** stories of the offseason is the move of Player X from Team Y.

Similarly in the fields of politics or movies.

What words can I use in this context similar to **most talk about**. The word I am looking for means a story that got everybody talking?

Answer (score 4):

There is *popular, buzzing, prominent, striking, newsworthy, trending*...but I think *most-talked-about* (or *most talked-about*) is mostly unavoidable if that is really what you want to say. That's why everybody's using it, and there's nothing wrong with it, although I believe most style books recommend that you use hyphens if it preceded a noun, as it is a compound adjective.

Comment: I would write *most talked-about*.

Comment: @snailplane: Hmm yes, I guess you could write it with or without hyphen, depending on whether you feel that *most* modifies only *talked* or *talked-about* as a while.